# Unison, systemd and logrotate

Tags: systemd, logrotate, unison

I have unison running under systemd to keep my local and remote NASs in sync.
The systemd config is thus:

```
[Unit]
Description=NAS Unision service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=nas
ExecStart=/usr/bin/unison borg

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And in ~nas/.unison/borg.prf I have configure unison to run with:

```
# Keep repeating every 15 mins.
repeat=900

# Log to the file which will be rotated by logrotate.
log=true
logfile=/var/log/unison-borg.log
```

logrotate is configure to rotate the log once per day:

```
# Rotation of the Unision logs
/var/log/unison-borg.log {
    dayly
    rotate 7
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    notifempty
    create 644 nas nas
}
```

My issue is that unison doesn't appear to open the log file with each repeat and thus when logrotate rotates the log file unsion-borg.log.1 gets the updates.

The man file for unison states that "Sending SIGUSR1 will close the logfile; the logfile
will be re-opened (and created, if needed) automatically, to allow for log rotation."

How should I do this in systemd?

Comment: Why is it important to do it in systemd? Why not in logrotate?

Answer (score 0):

Create the script /etc/logrotate.post.daily:

```
#!/bin.sh
systemctl status nas-borg | awk '/Main PID/{ print "kill -10 " $3 }' | sh
```

And modify the logroate.conf task to add the postrotate option:

```
/var/log/unison-borg.log {
    ...
    postrotate /etc/logrotate.post.daily
}
```

Comment: That seems like a long-winded way of doing `systemctl kill nas-borg`